# Working with dataset rows

Tags: c#, dataset, xamarin.android, rows, loops

I have a DataSet which I get from a webservice with which I populate a listview. So far I've been doing it like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dsGetAvailUsers.Tables[0].Rows) 
{
var item = new User();
item.sUserId = row ["sUserId"].ToString ();
item.UserDesc = row ["UserDesc"].ToString ();
item.UserIMG = row ["UserIMG"].ToString ();

listUsers.Add(item);
}
```

But that vas since I knew the names of each field since it was a list with fixed data and field names.

But now I'm getting lists which once have 10 fields per item and once 12, etc.
How would I iterate through rows "dynamically" and how then do I deal with them in my custom adapter (unknown field name and field count)?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but can't you just specify the column index?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What are you trying to do? Display all the data or just some of it?

Comment: I wanted anonymous probing of the DataSet. I answered my question below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that solves it all...

```
foreach (DataRow row in dsGetAvailUsers.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var item = new Dokument();
    int i = 0;
    item.Label = new Hashtable();
    item.array = new Hashtable();
    foreach (DataColumn _col in dsGetAvailUsers.Tables[0].Columns) 
    {
        item.Label.Add(i, _col.ColumnName);
        item.array.Add(_col.ColumnName,row[i].ToString());
        ++i;
    }
    listDokument.Add(item);
    RunOnUiThread (() => {DokumentAdapter.Add (item); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
foreach (DataRow row in dsGetAvailUsers.Tables[0].Rows) 
{
var item = new User();

 for (int j = 0; j < dsGetAvailUsers.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
 {
   if(dsGetAvailUsers.Tables[0].Columns[j].ColumnName == "sUserId")
      item.sUserId = row ["sUserId"].ToString ();
   else if(dsGetAvailUsers.Tables[0].Columns[j].ColumnName == "UserDesc")
      item.UserDesc= row ["UserDesc"].ToString ();
   .....
 }


listUsers.Add(item);
}
```